# doesnot add an image in child class using imagepicker?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, imagepicker

Error: Field '_image' should be initialized because its type 'File' doesn't allow null.

- 'File' is from 'dart:io'.
  File _image;
  ^^^^^^

code:

child: _image != null ? null : Image.file(_image,fit: BoxFit.fill,),

Answer (score 1):

Check this code,you need to use setState in image selection function to update the view or show the image

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      File? _image;
      final picker = ImagePicker();
    
      Future getImage() async {
        final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
        setState(() {
          if (pickedFile != null) {
            _image = File(pickedFile.path);
          } else {
            print('No image selected.');
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: _image == null
                ? Text('No image selected.')
                : Image.file(_image!),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: getImage,
            tooltip: 'Pick Image',
            child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I had a problem and got the following error, ```info: The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.``` This was because of the ```_image == null ? Text("No image selected")``` part. What is the fix for that. I saw the same thing used in a lot of places but I'm getting the above error. any reason?

Comment: it's null safety error i think try like this `File? _image;` @LakshanCosta

Comment: Thank you very much. Also I think a part of the body needs to change, ```: Image.file(_image),```   ------->  ``` Image.file(_image!),```

Comment: yeah,i forgot about that,i have updated the answer@LakshanCosta

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize _image using `File _image;` Then inside setState use `_image = File(pickedFile.path);` pickedFile is return from ImagePicker. Please send full code for more customized answer